# Why can simple functions not take the value $\infty$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

When one develops the theory of integration, why is it usually the case that simple functions **are not** allowed to take the value $\infty$?

Recall that if $(X,\mathcal{M})$ is a measureable space then a simple function is a measurable $s:X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ (here $[0,\infty)$ is endowed with its usual subspace topology which generates its Borel sets $\mathcal{B}[0,\infty)$) if $s$ can be written as a finite combination of indicators of sets in $\mathcal{M}$ with coefficients in $[0,\infty)$: $$s=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \mathbf{1}_{A_i},$$where $\alpha_i\in[0,\infty)$ for all $i=1,\dots, n$ and $A_i\in\mathcal{M}$ for all $i=1,\dots, n$.

Since integration theory is built to handle extended real-valued measurable functions, it seems silly that one not allow simple functions to have a coefficient of $\infty$.

As an example, let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and define the function $f(x) = \infty$ for all $x\in X$. This is a $(\mathcal{B}[0,\infty], \mathcal{M})$-measurable function, and it would seem to make sense to define $\int_X f\,d\mu = \infty\cdot \mu(X)$, since $f = \infty\cdot \mathbf{1}_X$, and therefore consider $f$ as a simple function. Of course, one can get the same answer by considering a sequence of simple functions (whose range is $[0,\infty)$) converging pointwise to $f$ and then taking the *definition* of $\int_X f\,d\mu$ to be the usual one, i.e., the supremum of the integrals of all simple functions less than $f$.

Long story short, it doesn't seem like we run into any problems if we allow simple functions to have $\infty$ as one of its coefficients. The best reason I can come up with as to why books (Rudin, Folland, etc.) are adamant about defining simple functions as not taking value $\infty$ is that it is not necessary to define the integral for "simple functions" that take value $\infty$; rather one can recover the integral of such functions by the "supremum definition" of the integral. But then again, this is simply a definition too, so is there any more generality in one approach versus the other?

By the way, [this previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935766/can-simple-functions-take-the-value-infinity) does not give a satisfying answer to this particular question.

Comment: In order to have $s(x)=\infty$ for some $x$, you would either have to allow infinite sums or some $\alpha_i=\infty$, hence $s(x)=\infty$ on a whole interval. Either of these two properties would make your "simple" function ugly. It is nicer to know that simple functions can be treated without any artificial rules of arithmetic involving $\infty$

Comment: Agree with Hagen. One of the answers I like in the previous thread said simples functions should be exactly that, simple. We can easily move to more general functions by taking the pointwise limit, and this covers infinite valued functions.

So the answer is yes you could define them to take infinite value, but there is not much utility in doing so. The usual construction works fine.

Comment: I am not doubting the usual construction and that it works, but rather wondering why it is the way it is. What is not "simple" about the following? Define simple functions by $s(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\mathbf{1}_{A_i}(x)$ where $\alpha_i\in [0,\infty]$ and let $\int_X s\,d\mu = \sum_{I=1}^{n} \alpha_i \mu(A_i)$, which is a well-defined number in $[0,\infty]$. Sure, my simple function possibly takes value $\infty$ on some measurable set, interval, etc. I don't understand why this isn't "simple". Maybe I am missing something more fundamental, but as of now, I cannot see it.

Comment: As another comment, is there anything particularly nasty about arithmetic in $[0,\infty]$? It seems pretty simple to me? Unless "simple" is reserved for adding real numbers, since this is the thing we have done since childhood. Just really curious on why one is less simple than the other. It's not obvious to me. Furthermore, why do you call arithmetic involving $\infty$ artificial? The arithmetic is what it is. It's a well-defined operator on $[0,\infty]$, and also makes intuitive sense. We require the arithmetic on $[0,\infty]$ when defining the integral of a simple function anyway.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst so it's really more of just the fact that there is not much utility in doing so and that "infinity" as a number is in some sense "less simple" (more abstract, less intuitive, etc.)? Would it be fair to say that the term "simple" function is subjective in nature? I'm sure there exist people who would consider either definition of a simple function "simple". My curiosity was more if somehow the theory broke down in some way by allowing for $\infty$ in a simple function.

Comment: yeah I'd say so, and I can't think why off the top of my head you can't define it on extended reals

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Yeah, same here. The theory is nice how it is. My question really just pertained to why in the theory/construction of integration did people decide to not allow $\infty$ for simple functions. And as you just pointed out, an equally good question is why can you not allow a simple function to have negative coefficients. I am not sure if the construction breaks down if you allow this, but it doesn't seem like it does if you allow $\infty$. At least for my question, it seems more like a subjective choice.

Comment: ah there is a good reason for non negative coefficients, we cannot easily define $\infty - \infty$ without taking limits

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst oh you are right. We actually do run into problems there. But you could keep going and ask if you can allow for coefficients in $[-\infty, \infty)$ or $(-\infty, \infty]$ for finite measure spaces. Perhaps this is a fine way of doing things in that setting. But then you have an unsatisfying theory, as it restricts to finite measure spaces opposed to arbitrary measure spaces. But then again, probability theory is all about finite measure spaces, so in that setting maybe there is no harm. But I'm sure that even the probabilists desire a theory that extends beyond them.

Comment: oh also, all mathematicians have already agreed on this definition haha, so that is one reason to use it

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Right haha, I'm definitely planning to continue to use the standard definition.